# Change Outlook365 ost file location

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have big ost file 15GB and my C drive is almost full

I need to move the ost file to D drive to give space for my c drive

My outlook is

[image]

and I am using Windows 10

I followed the instructions in many websites
https://kb.intermedia.net/article/1928

[image]

The problem is that my Email advanced options is different and does not have outlook data file settings button

[image]

I also tried other way using Data Files in Account Setting the browse button is disabled and I cannot cange the location of the file

[image]

How can I move my ost file to another directory?

Comment: @Ramhound How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I move my ost file to another directory?

The article you linked to describes a feature that was depreciated in Office 2013+, which means what you want, isn't possible unless you create a new Outlook profile.

> 1. Copy the existing .ost file to the new location that you want to use.
> 2. In Control Panel, type mail to search for the Mail item, and then open it. If there are two Mail items, choose the one that is labeled
>    with your version of Outlook, such as Microsoft Outlook 2013 or
>    Microsoft Outlook 15 for Outlook 2013, or Microsoft Outlook 2016 or
>    Microsoft Outlook 16 for Outlook 2016
> 3. Click **Show Profiles**.
> 4. Click **Add**
> 5. In the Profile Name box, type the name that you want to use for the new email profile, and then click OK
> 6. Click **Next** after Outlook finds your account information
> 7. After Outlook finishes the setup for your account, select the Change account settings option, and then click **Next**
> 8. In the Server Settings section, click **More Settings**
> 9. On the Advanced tab, click **Outlook Data File Settings**
> 10. Click **Browse**, browse to the .ost file that you copied in step 1, and then click **Open**.
> 11. Click **Finish** to finish the setup for your email account.
> 12. Open Control Panel, and then open the Mail.
> 13. Click **Always use this profile**, select the new profile that you created, and then click **OK**

Source: [You cannot change the location of the offline Outlook Data File (.ost) in Microsoft Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2752583/you-cannot-change-the-location-of-the-offline-outlook-data-file-ost-in)